# How import component vue in script laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to do a reference to a component vue like this link: https://jsfiddle.net/xmqgnbu3/1/.

But, in this code, the code component and js code are in the same page.
I am using laravel with vue and the components are in another folder (link: https://ibb.co/g3CvHz6)

I tried all this, but i have error in the "import" in "require":

```
@section('contenido')

<!-- CSRF Token --> 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<div id="app" class="container"> 
    <matricula ref="matri"></matricula> 
</div> 
<input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>

import MatriculaComponent from '../js/components/MatriculaComponent.vue';
let MatriculaComponent=require('../js/components/MatriculaComponent.vue');
var vm = new Vue({ el: '#app', components: { matricula } });

var vm=$("#app")
function createItem(){
    //this.$refs["matri"].Prueba();
    //vm.$refs.matri.Prueba();
    //vm['my-component'].Prueba();
    console.log("la referencia: "+this.$refs.matri.Prueba())
    //this.$refs.matricula.Prueba();
}
</script>

@endsection
```

I expect your help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main point is making a vue component and set the template and script there. then, after compile, you can put the component name whatever you want in blade.

FMI, you have to read [How to create and deal with vue component in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend#writing-vue-components)